# Randomly fade <div>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Basically I'm trying to merge the two scripts below for a project. My goal is to keep the functionality of the first link, where it fades in random divs at different intervals, but attach it to PaulPRO's version, in that it keeps looping over and over again, say every 5 seconds. Any help is greatly appreciated!

1. http://jsfiddle.net/cMQdj/1/  (thanks to mblase75)
2. http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/G4pxq/ (thanks to PaulPRO)

Comment: i think you have that the wrong way round .. 1st one loops .. 2nd doesnt ...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? You should do so, and come back with _specific_ problems related to your task.

Comment: So, randomly fade in certain `<div>`s with a slight staggering, and repeat every *n* seconds? A link to previous questions might help.

Comment: The combinations I tried just kept breaking the code and nothing would display. Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hows this ->

http://jsfiddle.net/G4pxq/9/

```
(function fadeInDiv(){
    var divs = $('.fadeIn');
        var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')){
        elem.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),fadeInDiv); 
    } else {
        elem.fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),fadeInDiv); 
    }
})();
```

### Update

Maintaining position / order :

http://jsfiddle.net/G4pxq/12/

```
$('.fadeIn').before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');

(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divs = $('.fadeIn');
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
         elem.prev().remove();
        elem.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);

    } else {

        elem.fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function() {
            elem.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
            fadeInDiv();
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you ManseUK. I bumped this answer up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your examples reversed.

If you want to loop Paul's example, just surround his code in a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) method.

`setInterval($('.fadeIn').before('<div>&nbsp;</div>'), 2000);`

Comment: I don't think that will work. You need to wrap it in a `function() {}`.